# Marshal.StructureToPtr throws "Typelib export: Type library in not registered" exception when executed

Tags: c#, windows

Plugin Data is defined as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PLUGIN_DATA
{
    public int paramterDataLength;
    public PLUGIN_PARAMETER_DATA[] pluginParameterData;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PLUGIN_PARAMETER_DATA
{
    public string version;
    public string name;
    public string data;
}
```

```
WindowHelper.PLUGIN_DATA pluginData = new WindowHelper.PLUGIN_DATA()
      {
          ParameterDataLength = 3,
          PluginParameterData = new[]
          {
              new WindowHelper.PLUGIN_PARAMETER_DATA { Name = "StartingPlugin", Version = "1", Data = "BD9B5012-4B81-4DBA-876E-DD6829208F3A" },
              new WindowHelper.PLUGIN_PARAMETER_DATA { Name = "StartingPluginParameter", Version = "1", Data = "{ \"parameterModelVersion\":1,\"parameterModelJson\":\"{\"parameterData\":{\"star-rating\":5}}\"}"},
              new WindowHelper.PLUGIN_PARAMETER_DATA { Name = "StartingPluginPriority", Version = "1", Data = "1" }
          }
      };
```

```
var pluginDataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(pluginData);
pluginDataBuff = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(pluginDataSize);
```

When I execute the following line:

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(pluginData, pluginDataBuff, false);
```

I get the exception

> Typelib export: Type library is not registered (Ox80131165)

and the `ex.Source` is `System.Private.CoreLib`

Any help with how to remedy this exception is very much appreciated.

```
public static int SendMessageToWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint wParam, PLUGIN_DATA pluginData, bool throwExceptions = false)
{
    var result = 0;
    var copyData = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
    var copyDataBuff = IntPtr.Zero;
    var pluginDataBuff = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        var pluginDataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(pluginData);
        pluginDataBuff = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(pluginDataSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(pluginData, pluginDataBuff, false);
```

Comment: Maybe include the full call stack when you get this?

Comment: call stack is: System.StubHelpers.MngdSafeArrayMarshaler.ConvertSpaceToNative(IntPtr pMarshalState, Object& pManagedHome, IntPtr pNativeHome)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(Object structure, IntPtr ptr, Boolean fDeleteOld)
   at Dell.Client.Framework.UX.WPF.WindowHelper.SendMessageToWindow(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 wParam, PLUGIN_DATA pluginData, Boolean throwExceptions) in D:\DUCA294EV1.1\src\Dell.Client.Framework.UX.WPF\WindowHelper.cs:line 512

Comment: Line 512 is the call to  Marshal.StructureToPtr(pluginData, pluginDataBuff, false);

Comment: This issue happens when the structure being dealt with itself contains a structure.  The PLUGIN_DATA structure above contains a member, pluginParameterData, that is an array of PLUGIN_PARAMETER_DATA structures.  If I don't initialize pluginParameterData, then Marshal.StructureToPtr will work with no issues.  I will post the fix for this issue when I verify it.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with nested structures (structures that contain structures), the PLUGIN_DATA structure detailed above contains a member public PLUGIN_PARAMETER_DATA[] pluginParameterData; which is a variable length array.

Marshal is not able to deal with a variable length array. I was able to better deal with this by not using the PLUGIN_DATA structure at all, and just creating an array of PLUGIN_PARAMETER_DATA. NOTE that the PLUGIN_PARAMETER_DATA structure contains three variable length strings.  I was only able to deal with these strings if I declared a MarshalAs with a SizeConst value ... i.e. [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)] . I tried other notations but they did not provide a successful outcome.

I did find the URL https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/COPYDATASTRUCT.html quite useful.  Hopefully others will as well.